# Can someone Inject malicious SQL to my SQL query?

Tags: vulnerability, sql-injection

I build a simple chat with `MySQL`. It has a table called `users` and two colums: `id` and `username`. I use the following query to extract username and ID by ID.

Is there a way someone can Inject malicios SQL ? and How ?

**Limit is used to only allow 1 result to come out**

```
$query = 'SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id=' . $id . ' LIMIT 1';
```

Comment: It depends on how you get the `$id` variable and process it in your code before placing it in the query. If a user can manipulate the variable value and can insert SQL, they can perform sql injection.

Comment: @roy.stultiens What do you mean? I don't do anything with it.

Comment: Where does the variable come from? Also, why are you getting the ID from the database if you already have it?

Comment: @roy.stultiens I let users to check by ID if user already exists.

Comment: That is almost certainly vulnerable, unless $id is _really, really_ carefully validated elsewhere. Someone can possibly inject SQL commands into the $id variable. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: Very much yes.  This is the easiest kind of SQL injection possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `$id` is a variable which is obtained from user input, then this is a textbook example of an SQL injection.

Your code will work if the `$id` is a numeric string like `42`. But imagine what will happen if someone enters this string as their id:

```
' OR 1 = 1 --
```

Then the SQL query sent to the database will read:

```
SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id='' OR 1 = 1 --' LIMIT 1
```

As you might know `--` is a comment in SQL. So the limit is deactivated. Further, `OR 1 = 1` will be true on every single line, so this will return **all** usernames and id's.

But it gets even better: What about this ID?

```
42'; DROP TABLE users --
```

The character `;` is used to separate two SQL queries in one line. So you get the following line of SQL:

```
SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id='42'; DROP TABLE users --' LIMIT 1
```

Most database drivers will execute both of these queries, thus deleting your users table.

Comment: Thanks. Few questions. `DROP TABLE users`, How will they know the table `users`? Also, how can I can fix these vulnerabilities ?

Comment: @harabatahat You should never expect that your table names will stay secret. That would be security through obscurity. How to fix these vulnerabilities depends on what library you are using. The code in your question looks like PHP to me. In that case you should stop using the `mysql_` library and should use `mysqli` instead with its [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). They are not just faster, they are also more secure because the API automatically escapes string delimeters in input.

Comment: Note that with an SQL injection vulnerability an attacker can easily find out what your tables are called by querying the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't assume you can trust the variable

Philipp has already given the examples on how to abuse this in his [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/236576/70406) and there's no need to repeat that. Despite it depends on whether the `$id` comes directly from the user input or not, you shouldn't assume it will stay that way during the whole lifecycle of the application. If the ID currently e.g.

- comes from a result of another SQL-query always outputting a valid integer or
- is converted to integer (using [`(int)` or `(integer)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) [*casts*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.cast.php) or [`intval($id)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function),

someone might later use other sources for it while calling your function/method or recycling code from it.

### Use *prepared statements* and *parameterized queries*

It's better to keep forming SQL queries completely isolated from the data. There's not much that isn't already covered e.g. OWASP [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), and with PHP the typical choice would be to use *prepared statements* and *parameterized queries*.

Some good examples for both MySQLi and PDO:

- W3Schools: [PHP MySQL Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)
- PHP Manual: [MySQLi: Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- PHP Manual: [PDO: Prepared statements and stored procedures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)